# Decoding Cookie Using cookie-parser

Tags: javascript, express, express-session

I am trying to decode a cookie (with no success) that looks like the following: `s%3Ak0tBm_lnBeH4G5pPIbbFKktQl0l4pNU8.d2ZbSvwFjkmVWfcS9Wn0%2Fi2oSnTYI09krfOOWJAXirE`.

It was made using the express-session module.

I have tried doing something like this:

`const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
console.log(cookieParser.signedCookie("s%3Ak0tBm_lnBeH4G5pPIbbFKktQl0l4pNU8.d2ZbSvwFjkmVWfcS9Wn0%2Fi2oSnTYI09krfOOWJAXirE", "jksadhjk123io12ejnmlad'132hv8891"));`

The output of this is the first parameter to signedCookie ("s%3Ak0tBm_..."). I expect something similar to:

`{
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2019-09-08T22:33:17.317Z,
     originalMaxAge: 3600000,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: false,
     domain: null,
     sameSite: true
   },
   userID: 5d6ffe165d6eb10a7905c633
}`

Answer (score 2):

It seems the signature could not be validated between the string and the supplied `secret`. Note the syntax is:

```
cookieParser.signedCookie(str, secret);
```

See [this reference](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html#cookieparsersignedcookiestr-secret), which says both,

> If the value was not signed, the original value is returned.

and

> If the value was signed but the signature could not be validated,
>   false is returned.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: Your cookie value is URL encoded and that won't work with `cookie-parser` until you decode it.**

I'm assuming you used express's [res.cookie()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie) method to set and sign the original cookie. This requires you also make use of the second-party [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) middleware, per express's documentation for `res.cookie`:

> When using cookie-parser middleware, this method also supports signed cookies. Simply include the signed option set to true. Then res.cookie() will use the secret passed to cookieParser(secret) to sign the value.

When express signs a cookie, it [appends a ":s" to the front of the cookie](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L844-L846). Here's the bit of code from express's `response.js` on GitHub:

```
if (signed) {
  val = 's:' + sign(val, secret);
}
```

So. It appears your cookie value was encoded when it was originally set (by default, express uses `encodeURIComponent`). The encoded value of ":s" becomes "%3s", and your cookie value you provided begins `s%3Ak0tBm...`

Providing an encoded value to `cookie-parser.signedCookie` [will not work](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser/blob/master/index.js#L134-L136), as you can see if you inspect its code:

```
if (str.substr(0, 2) !== 's:') {
  return str
}
```

If you're using `cookie-parser` as express middleware upstream from the code in question, cookie values **will be** properly decoded by the middleware and available to you at `req.signedCookies`. But if you're using the `signedCookie` method ad-hoc, you'll need to decode it yourself first, i.e. `decodeURIComponent`.

Lastly, you can also take a look at the `encode` option you can provide to `res.cookie` for a roll-your-own encoding option.

Once you're able to provide a properly decoded value to `cookie-parser`, it'll properly parse your signed cookie value.